# Mysql unique exception. Is such a thing possible?

Tags: mysql, exception, unique

I need to have a field `UNIQUE` in a table mysql, but with an exception.

For example I need the field to be uniquely assigned, but sometimes it could be `ANONYMOUS` or NULL.

- field_mail: `mrwhite@gmail.com`,
- field_mail: `sometext@yahoo.com`,
- field_mail: `missgreen@gmail.com`,
- field_mail: `ANONYMOUS`,
- field_mail: `NULL`,
- field_mail: `NULL`,
- field_mail: `mrsbrown@gmail.com`,
- field_mail: `ANONYMOUS`,
- field_mail: ...

Thx! :)

Comment: Easy enough to test..

Comment: Multiple nulls are allowed with unique index, but not any other values.

Comment: But you could ditch the unique and validate in a trigger.

Comment: So, I have to create a secondary boolean field, for example `field_mail_anonymous` (0 or 1).. and leave `NULL` primary field..

Comment: Now you are approaching a question albeit a different one for which you should raise a new question

Comment: It's better to drop ANONYMOUS and use only NULL. In a view you can use `COALESCE(field_mail , 'ANONYMOUS')`.

Comment: Could you help me with the "trigger" way? I usually validate fields from PHP, and not use trigger from MYSQL..